# How do i read text from an Alert(ios) in calabash

Tags: ios, xcode, cucumber, calabash

How can I access the text of an alertview on iOS in my **calabash/cucumber** tests?

```
NSString *msgString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No: %@\n Latitude: %f\n Longitude: %f", wrapper.no, wrapper.latitude, wrapper.longitude];
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Really reset?" message:@"msgString" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
// optional - add more buttons:
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
[alert show];
```

I want to assert that the alert has the expected content:

```
Feature: Running a test
  As a user using a phone connected to the internet
  I want to have correct sample data retrieved from cache or net
  So I can read the values of the tableview

   Scenario: Testing retrieved data

  Given the app is running
  Then I press "Refresh"
  Then I should see "Some value"
  Then I press "Some value"
  Then I should /*See an alert with "myMessage"*/
  Then I press "OK"

  And take picture
```

So if i change the string to simply "No:" and discard everything else from the string, it does actually seem to work, but i cant get it running with my more complex string :(

Comment: Actually when you want to read the message? After you tap on the alert view button?

Comment: When the alert is visible

Comment: After making [alert show]; call you can read it as given in the answer posted already :

Comment: None of the answers are calabash tests

Comment: If you are not familiar with calabash, you probably do not have the answer I am after. Ofcourse I am running the tests in runtime!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution to add newline support is to take the variables out of the string in the features so that the newline can be added by the ruby code:

```
Then I see a popup with latitude 10 and longitude 20
```

Calls:

```
Then /^I see a popup with latitude (\d+) and longitude (\d+)$/ do |lat, lon|
  msg = "Latitude:#{lat}\nLongitude:#{lon}"
  should_see_alert_with_text msg
end
```

Using:

```
def should_see_alert_with_text (text)
  wait_poll(:until_exists => 'alertView', :timeout => 5) do
    actual = query('alertView child label', :text).first
    unless actual.eql? text
      screenshot_and_raise "should see alert view with message '#{text}' but found '#{actual}'"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Inside your def You could use `wait_for_elements_exist(["alertView child label marked:'#{text}'
"], :timeout => 5)`

Answer (score 4):

I tested this code and its working fine

inside step definition file (ProjectName/features/step_definitions/my_first_steps.rb) add

```
Then /^I see an alert with "([^\"]*)" text$/ do |message|
    result = query("view:'UIAlertView' label text:'#{message}'").empty?
    if result
        screenshot_and_raise "could not find text field with AlertView with text '#{message}'"
    end
    sleep(STEP_PAUSE)
end
```

and in feature file

```
Then I see an alert with "Email cannot be empty." text
```

if text doesn't match with the message it will take a screenshot and fails the test

**But this is working for your custom alerts not on system alerts..!!**

this will help you if you need to read the message from alert

open `$ calabash-ios console` and

query like `query("view:'UIAlertView'",:message)`

add more....

Or You can use something like

```
Then /^I wait until alert with text "([^\"]*)" and press "([^\"]*)" button$/ do |message, button|

  wait_for_elements_exist(["alertView child label marked:'#{message}'"], :timeout => 30,  :retry_frequency => 0.3,:timeout_message => "Timed out waiting..",:screenshot_on_error => true )
    if element_exists("alertView child label marked:'#{message}'")
      touch("button marked:'#{button}'")
      sleep(STEP_PAUSE)
    else
      screenshot_and_raise "Alert Element not found"
    end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean custom alerts? I cant get this working as you wrote it.

Comment: custom alerts means the one you make like this in side your code    `UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", "") otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];`

Comment: @David : Did you follow the steps correctly can you show me your code, Any error messages you get ? you need to replace the message text "Email cannot be empty." with your one.and you need to give wait time few seconds to appear the alert before you execute this code part. or else there is a function to wait until the screen you defined to appear and then execute your code.

Comment: Im sorry, then i guess im using a custom alertView. The message in my case is actually set from a NSString (I updated my question), so this approach wont work?

Comment: hm.. then you need to investigate you alert view and its components using `$ calabash-ios console` and then you can try to query correct identifier like here [link]https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/05-Query-syntax  if you successfully get your text from alert to this console then write a ruby function call it from gherkin.

Comment: The problems seems to appear due to newline "\n" in the string

Comment: @David even-though my answer is not worked for your special case it works on normal alerts fine. so can you please marked it as correct answer for other users benefit. and when you find the answer to your special case publish your answer with special conditions. Thanks.

Comment: @david you can read your message using `$ calabash-ios console`  and query like `query("view:'UIAlertView'",:message)` then you can use it.

Answer (score 4):

For iOS 7 and above: following calabash code will work fine.

```
Then I should see "your text here"
And I should see "Call XXX"
And I should see "Cancel"
```

Works for me.

Comment: OK! Works, for me as well, make sure the message you are asserting is exactly the message that is shown not a substring of it!

Answer (score 1):

The link to the calabash-ios issue was buried in the comments.

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/149

In that issue, I provide an example of how to handle search for text with newlines.

Karl also suggests writing the step with multi-line strings ("pystrings")

```
Then I see an alert with text:
"""
Latitude:59
Longitude:17
"""
```